# How to toggle div's presence instead of visibility

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to toggle a div's presence when a certain statement is true.

ATM I'm using the following JavaScript/AJAX:

```
   function checkSession() {
    $.ajax({
            url:  '/dev/php/checkSession.php',
            type: 'POST',
            error: function(ja){
                console.log(ja);
            },      
            success: function(response) {
                if(response == "")
                {
                var elem = document.getElementById("liitem");
                elem.innerHTML = "Inloggen";
                var elem2 = document.getElementById("aanmelden");
                elem2.style.visibility = 'visible';
                }

            else {
                sessionmaybe = response;
                var elem = document.getElementById("liitem");
                elem.innerHTML = 'Uitloggen';
                var elem2 = document.getElementById("aanmelden");
                elem2.style.visibility = 'hidden';
            }
            }
        })
}
```

The problem is that when I'm resizing the window the div still has style.

[image]

Thanks to floating, normally the menu would just take it's place right beside the logo.

Is there a way to toggle the style of the div?

Comment: If you use `display: none` then the element will still exist in the DOM, but won't take up any space

Comment: Well that was easy, thanks

Comment: No problem. I added it as an answer for you, and also simplified your code slightly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use `display: none` then the element will still exist in the DOM, but won't take up any space. As you're using jQuery you can simplify this to call either `show()`/`hide()` or use `toggle()`:

```
function checkSession() {
  $.ajax({
    url:  '/dev/php/checkSession.php',
    type: 'POST',
    error: function(ja) {
      console.log(ja);
    },      
    success: function(response) {
      $("#liitem").text(response == "" ? 'Inloggen' : 'Uitloggen');
      $("#aanmelden").toggle(response == "");
    }
  });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

use `style.display= "none"`, given `visibilty` will hide the element and leave the space where the DOM element would have been, unlike `display:none` which will remove from the DOM

From **[MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/visibility)**

> **hidden**
>
> The box is invisible (fully transparent, nothing is drawn), but still affects layout.  Descendants of the element will be visible if
>   they have visibility:visible (this doesn't work in IE up to version
>   7).

```
  function checkSession() {
    $.ajax({
            url:  '/dev/php/checkSession.php',
            type: 'POST',
            error: function(ja){
                console.log(ja);
            },      
            success: function(response) {
                if(response == "")
                {
                var elem = document.getElementById("liitem");
                elem.innerHTML = "Inloggen";
                var elem2 = document.getElementById("aanmelden");
                elem2.style.style.display = 'inline-block'; // whatever property fits better here
                }

            else {
                sessionmaybe = response;
                var elem = document.getElementById("liitem");
                elem.innerHTML = 'Uitloggen';
                var elem2 = document.getElementById("aanmelden");
                elem2.style.style.display = 'none';
            }
            }
        })
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the `display: none` & `display: block` properties instead of `visibility`. `display` doesn't take up space in your DOM unlike `visibility`.

However, any `transition` or `animation` associated with your `.aanmelden` element will be gone now as `display` renders states instead of a step function required to make transitions.

```
   function checkSession() {
    $.ajax({
            url:  '/dev/php/checkSession.php',
            type: 'POST',
            error: function(ja){
                console.log(ja);
            },      
            success: function(response) {
                if(response == "")
                {
                var elem = document.getElementById("liitem");
                elem.innerHTML = "Inloggen";
                var elem2 = document.getElementById("aanmelden");
                elem2.style.display = 'block';
                }

            else {
                sessionmaybe = response;
                var elem = document.getElementById("liitem");
                elem.innerHTML = 'Uitloggen';
                var elem2 = document.getElementById("aanmelden");
                elem2.style.display = 'none';
            }
            }
        })
}
```